# A simpler solution to a limit question?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, probability-limit-theorems

Okay I saw this limit question in Thomas' Calculus 12th Edition:

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan3x}{\sin8x}$

The answer is $\frac{3}{8}$.

I was able to get the correct answer using this ridiculously lengthy and messed up rubbish...

[image: My solution]

... but I have a feeling there should a simpler, more concise and more elegant solution. Perhaps there is something I am missing? Maybe a trig identity? Or a theorem?

Comment: l'Hôpital or Taylor?

Comment: $\cdots =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin 3x}{\sin 8x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{3}{8}\right)\left( \frac{\sin 3x}{3x}\right)\left( \frac{8x}{\sin 8x}\right)$

Comment: I still can't understand why L.F. didn't make this an answer: very nice trick! +1

Comment: @DonAntonio yeah, I was actually waiting for him to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know about equivalents, then you can say that $\tan(y)$ is equivalent to $y$ in zero and $\sin(y)$ is equivalent to $y$ in $0$. This gives that the limit you're looking is the same as the limit, when $x$ tends to $0$, of $\frac{8x}{3x}$, which is of course $\frac{8}{3}$.

Here is an alternative proof if you don't know about equivalents:

\begin{align}
\frac{\tan(3x)}{\sin(8x)} &= \frac{3}{8} \frac{\tan(3x)}{3x} \frac{8x}{\sin(8x)} \\
&= \frac{3}{8} \frac{\sin(3x)}{3x} \frac{1}{\cos(3x)} \frac{8x}{\sin(8x)}.
\end{align}

These computations are done for $x$ close to $0$ but not equal to $0$ so that the denominators don't vanish. You certainly know that $\frac{\sin(y)}{y}$ tends to $1$ when $y$ tends to $0$. By composition and the fact that $\cos(0)$ is $1$, this shows that the three fractions tend to $1$, hence the result.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was both intuitive and helpful. :)